# How to get JSP scriptlet value in struts tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Here is my code:

```
<% request.setAttribute("lcItem", "Hello"); %>
```

If I do as following, I'm not getting the value:

```
<s:property value="%{lcItem}" />
<s:property value="lcItem" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works perfectly..

```
<%       
   request.setAttribute("lcItem", LeftContentItem);
%>

<s:property value="#request['lcItem']" />
```

Note: According to the Scope we use we should specify the #request .. etc

Comment: Aha thats good. But I don't like this thing. Its so different that you can't intelligently guess. In fact, I like neither Struts nor Struts 2. Anyway, at least it worked for you, I am happy.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari Fortunately, you don't have to guess, because there's documentation.

Comment: @Dave: That simply means it's not intuitive enough. And that's what I actually meant, it's different what we used to do with EL/JSTL.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari Not everything is the same as everything else, I guess. OGNL brings a lot to the table, and the value stack is both a context and a stack. That flexibility comes with a price if you use it-although I see no reason to not just use JSP EL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code 2 ways

1. **`<% request.setAttribute("lcItem", "Hello"); %>`**
2. **`<% pageContext.setAttribute("lcItem", "Hello"); %>`**

then if you want to access these values in Struts2 Components you might use **#attr.** as prefix.

Example

**`<s:property value="#attr.lcItem">`**

Note: It will work fine with *request* and *"pageContext"*.

```
<s:property value="lcItem" /> will not work because "lcItem" is not available in the Value Stack.
```