# Insert value in textfield - struts2+liferay

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, liferay

in my jsp I have this code:

```
.....
    // get userid
    long userid = com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUserId(request);
    String userName = com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUserName(userid , "guest");
    %> 

    <s:textfield name="user" value="<%=userName%>"></s:textfield>
```

I am not able to display in the textfield the username value.

Can you help me,please.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JSP scriptlet value in struts tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724887/how-to-get-jsp-scriptlet-value-in-struts-tag)

Comment: liferay has no impact on this question you just need to use a scriptlet variable in a s2 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scriptlets are not allowed to use with the Struts tags. And you cannot access the the scripting variable `userName` because it's not on the value stack. To make it available just create a new variable in the value stack that has a value of the scripting variable.

```
<s:set var="userName"><%=userName%></s:set>
<s:textfield name="user" value="%{#userName}"/>
```

Another approach that is not expected is to make use of known containers like request that are accessible to the struts tags.

```
<% request.setAttribute("userName", userName); %>
<s:textfield name="user" value="%{#request.userName}"/>
```

You may notice the difference that in the first example the new variable is created and scripting variable passed by value as string printed to the out. In the second example the scripting variable passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks it works!!!If I want to retreive the user directly from my java class, how I have to do?Thanks

Comment: Associate it to the action and it will be available, the action is on the top of the value stack, so you will not need use of `#`. make sure it's a java bean and has accessors in the action too. Then reference it like `user.name`.

Comment: Do you hava an example,please?

Comment: I have created a jsp and the class Action (with struts2) and Model...If I want to obtain the username in my class Action I don't undestand what I have to do..

Comment: Proper name the textfilds, i.e. `model.user.userName` if you are not implementing `ModelDriven` like in [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html) example and [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/)